# Do i need to do declare a channel info in dsl always?

Tags: spring-integration

Do i need to do declare a channel in dsl always. In XML Version, we don't need to do  for all the channels in the flow.

```
@Bean(name = "reply")
public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read Spring Integration Java DSL [Reference Manual](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/). There is some info on the matter.

In the DSL you even can omit the mentioning for channels:

```
.handle()
.split()
.transform()
.aggregate()
```

and yes, you can finish one flow with just a `.channel("foo")` and start another one with it as well:

```
IntegreationFlows.from("foo")
```

For those cases when your application starts swearing like `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, you don't have choice unless declare `MessageChannel` `@Bean`.